# OpenGl ES : Make a skybox look realistic

Tags: opengl-es

I'm having a trouble with a skybox.
Everything is working fine, but we really feels like we are in a cube when the camera is in the middle (or everywhere else), the front face contains a part of the ground present un bottom face and we really feels the 90° angle between them.
Any idea to improve this ?

NB. I already edited the images so the colors are the same and desactivated any light effect

**Edited on 10/10**

What I do now is this (mix OpenGL & pseudocode)

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glEnable(GL_DEPH_TEST)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
Define_skybox (set vertices/texture coords; bind them on triangles)
glEnable(GL_DEPH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustumf(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, m_near, m_far) 
     with : m_fov = 90.0f; m_near = 0.1f; ymax = m_near * tan(m_fov * PI / 360); ymin = -ymax; xmax = ymax; xmin = -xmax;
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity();
Create 3 vect (center, eye, up) with spherical coordinate for my camera rotation
    eye(0;0;0), up (0; 1; 0), 
    center is calculated from rotation angle & spherical coordiantes
modelviewmatrix = glulookat(eye, center, up);
glLoadMatrix(modelviewmatrix);
```

Answer (score 2):

Where's your vantage point in relation of the cube? The camera must be in the exact center of the cube and the cube faces being rendered using a planar, center perspective projection with a 90° FOV. If you create your skybox that way, it should not "feel" like a cube.

#### Update due to comments

Principal operation when drawing a skybox (pseudocode)

```
render_scene_with_skybox():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE) # disable depth writes
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    set_projection()
    set_modelview(orientation=camera.orientation, location=(0,0,0))

    draw_skybox() # the skybox spans from -1 to 1 in either direction

    # those should be really on-demand
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)

    set_modelview(orientation=camera.orientation, location=camera.location)
    draw_scene()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but i'm really noob in openGL so it's hard for me to make the relation between the words you use and the OpenGL functions, can you be more precise please ?

Comment: @IggY: This is not really about OpenGL but geometry. It's difficult to pack this into only a comment. But what you really must understand is, that OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's more like sophisticated pencils and paper. Once you got that mental barrier down, things get a lot easier. In the case of a skybox, well, it's only the projection that must match. But the modelview part is completely separated from the rest of the scene. Let me write this into a working skybox example. Could take a little while though ;)

Comment: @IggY: Well, the textures you use are definitely not working for a skybox. What you need images that actually work for a skybox. You can also find them by the name "Environment map" or similar. But it's really important that the images have been made in the right way. Looking at what you have it's almost as if you took cylindric panoramic images. Those usually don't work, because they assume a cylinder around your viewer.

Comment: Okay, those cylinder projection now really call for an exhaustive tutorial… So much to do, so little time.

Comment: I made those images by taking screenshot of a 3D scene with 90° FOV, making 90° rotation each time...so are you sure they won't work ? Maybe my problem is the way I make my projection ?

Comment: @IggY: Well, are you sure it's the right 90° FOV? A lot of people get that one wrong. Technically what you want is a `glFrustum(-a, a, -a, a, a, far);` projection into a quadratic viewport.

Comment: Yes i'm 100% sure my screenshot were took with 90° FOV (all the scene is represented in my skybox, nothing miss, nothing is twice present, so it must mathematicly be a 90° fov).
And I make a glFrustumf(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, m_near, m_far) with :

m_fov = 90.0f;
m_near = 0.1f;
ymax = m_near * tan(m_fov * PI / 360);
ymin = -ymax;
xmax = ymax;
xmin = -xmax;

Comment: Well, another thing: The way your view into the cube looks you're not centered within the cube. That's important as well. Suggestion: This evening, after work I'll finish the skybox / skycylinder example program and you can look at it.

Comment: for now I was centered in (0;0;-0.7) because I want my camera to be in front of a model on the ground (and if I cented it in (0;0;0) my model have to fly or I look at it from too high point of view). But when i'm in (0;0;0) the perspective is a little bit better (not perfect, but not as bad as (0;0;-0.7)

Comment: (should we move this discussion to the "chat" ? I'm new here and not sure about concenquences it'll have)

Comment: @IggY: With your rep being so low, chat won't work. It's not a problem either, because all those comments are relevant to the answer. Maybe a moderator may edit them into the answer itself later.

Comment: @IggY: Anyway, now we're getting close. Your problem is, that you assume that there is a) a camera and b) that you can place that camera only once in the scene. The trick about rendering a skybox is, that you always keep the "camera" in the center of the skybox (0,0,0), but move it to the desired position when drawing your world. OpenGL is not a scene graph. Heck there's not even a camera, all it does is throwing triangles at the screen, one triangle at a time. Once it drew something it's done with and forgets about it.

Comment: I think all I need to understand is "The trick about rendering a skybox is, that you always keep the "camera" in the center of the skybox (0,0,0), but move it to the desired position when drawing your world" ^^ but I can't figure how to do this because, as I told before, what if I want my camera to be in front of a model at 0;0;-1 ? if I draw my scene 0;0;0 and then make a translation, the perspective wont be good right ?